# Multiple bean binding in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Suppose I want to fill two or three different beans with Spring 3 mvc how do I do that given that `<form:form>` only supports one `modelAttribute`? And what if I have some nested beans?

Obviously I don't want to create a "BIG" bean that then I use to fill'em all...

Comment: "Obviously I don't want to create a "BIG" bean that then I use to fill'em all".... why not?  It's the obvious and simple solution.

Comment: If you don't like 1 "big" bean, why not have one `extend` another?  Then you can keep beans separate for code clarity, but have 1 bean that Spring can understand in the form context.

Comment: The latter is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is create a new command class and use object composition.

```
public class MyCommandClass implements Serializable {
   private MyFirstBean myFirstBean;
   private MySecondBean mySecondBean;
   // other beans, getters and setters, etc.
}
```

Your form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="myCommand">
<form:input path="myFirstBean.someProperty" ... />
<form:input path="mySecondBean.someOtherProp" ... />
</form:form>
```