# How to submit nested Objects in Spring MVC 3?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can I submit a spring form if my bean has other beans?

Lets say I have these classes:

```
public class SoccerLeague{
//Imagine person as a simple bean name and lastname attributes.
private List<Person> staff;
private List<Person> soccerPlayers;
private String name;
private Calendar dateOfOrigin;
//...Getters and Setters

}
```

I want to make my form to submit the name and dateOfOrigin of the soccer league and I want to capture the attributes of a staff from the league. Something like create the league and then do:
    staff.add(staffFromSubmit);

Its this posible? What are the alternatives?

Comment: Do you want to submit the soccer league and the person with the same form with one submit, or are these separate submits?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I would look at the addAll(Collection c) method of List. Put all of the data you want to add in any object which implements Collection i.e. ArrayList or Vector and then pass it to the addAll method.

Comment: I just want to capture one Staff of the soccer league not a entire list.

Comment: If you are just trying to add to the list just have the submit function return a Person and add that to the list.

public Person submit(){
     //your code here
     return new Person(constructor);
}

Comment: Can you post a link with an example using mvc3?

Comment: general: http://www.commonj.com/blogs/2012/02/21/spring-mvc3-tutorial-inroduction-setup-hello-world/

dealing with forms: http://www.commonj.com/blogs/2012/08/22/spring-mvc-3-tutorial-simple-forms-handling/

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

I just have to create a wrapper bean and use it as command object. Here is the link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747567/multiple-bean-binding-in-spring)